# Apache: Alias to directory for VirtualHost in a separate configuration file

Tags: apache, apache2

I would like to create an alias for a directory, but I would like to do this in a separate configuration file than where I have defined my `VirtualHost` block.

Example:

`default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myserver.example.com
        DocumentRoot /path/to/my/site
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

In a separate file: `alias.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myserver.example.com
        Alias /path/to/directory/in/another/location
</VirtualHost>
```

I do not want to put this alias in my primary configuration file. When I have two `VirtualHost` blocks with the same `ServerName` apache does not start and produces an error.

Is this possible?

Comment: No.  1 virtualhost with it's configuration only.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Include` to do that.

Ex:

```
httpd.conf
----------

    <VirtualHost *:80>

        ... SOME CONFIGURATION ...

        Include conf/extra_config.conf

    </VirtualHost>

extra_config.conf
-----------------

    Alias /alias/ /somewhere
```

Since extra_config.conf was Included in the context of the VirtualHost, it will apply to this one.  You cannot have two times the same VirtualHost with the same ServerName anywhere.